# Oracle Regex_like function: returning what failed

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql, error-handling, regexp-like

I have an oracle function that is returning whether an email address is valid or not

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION valid_email (p_email in varchar2)
                                      return string is
  v_return  varchar2(255);
  cemailregexp constant varchar2(1000) := '^[a-z0-9!#$%&''*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(\.[a-z0-9!#$%&''*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@([a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+([A-Z]{2}|arpa|biz|com|info|intww|name|net|org|pro|aero|asia|cat|coop|edu|gov|jobs|mil|mobi|museum|pro|tel|travel|post)$';

BEGIN
  if regexp_like(p_email,cemailregexp,'i') then
     v_return := p_email;
  else
     v_return := null;
  end if;
  return v_return;

END;
```

if the email passes the regex, it returns the email, otherwise the return result is NULL

What I would love to know is what part of the input string failed, why did the regex_like fail?

instead of retuning just null if bad, maybe a new variable for reason

i would like email mgptva;d@uclin2.berkeley.edu to return:

v_return_msg= "invalid character ';' at position 7

I am sorry for not including my attempts toward this, I dont even know where to start, google searching hasnt been fruitful

Comment: this is pretty ambitious as it is; for example, the standard allows @ in the local part of an email address, if it is escaped with a \, and it allows the domain to be a four-part IP address in square brackets. For example, Foo\@Bar@[192.232.96.4] is a legitimate format for an email address. Your regexp doesn't allow for either. So back to your question: Do you want to check for every single rule in the book, or just point out the most obvious violations (no @ or no domain or more than one un-escaped @ or total email string too long)? The latter perhaps makes some sense.

Comment: yea we are going with just most obvious violations...“Joe\\Blow”@example.com is an actual legitimately formed email address, but doesnt pass the regex...just trying to filter the obvious to prevent data entry mistakes

Comment: Your best bet imho would be a simple parser. I doubt that this can be handled by a regex engine, with reasonable effort at least - certainly oracle's isn't up to par for this. Perl's regex implementation might be possible.

Comment: @mathguy see previous comment forgot to tag you

Comment: I did a quick search and found this which may help: http://www.oratable.com/email-validation/.  Good luck.

Comment: Why not just use another regex to test for illegal characters? You could just add more regexes for the other conditions too.

Comment: Maintaining a list of non-2char TLDs in your regex is a fool's errand I'm afraid. I would go with user272735's zen approach. TLDs have now proliferated so wildly that your list is the tip of the iceberg. Take a look at http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt . There is even .lamborghini and .sucks

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions either match or don't match. That's very much everything you get out of them.

Email addresses are complex and very difficult to validate with a regular expression. If your core business is not to build an email address validator I recommend that don't waste your time here anymore but move on.

I very much agree with this article [Stop Validating Email Addresses With Regex](https://davidcel.is/posts/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/) and my canonical email verification is:

```
create or replace function is_valid_email(p_email in varchar2) return number is
begin
  return regexp_count(p_email, '^\S+@\S+\.\S+$');
end;
```

If you want to see one state of the art implementation check Perl's [Email::Valid](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/Email-Valid-1.200/) module.